# Topological group admits up to isomorphism only one smooth structure turning it into a Lie group.

Tags: lie-groups

> **proposition :** Let $G$ be a Lie group.  Then $G$ as a topological group admits, up to isomorphism, only one differentiable structure
> turning it into a Lie group.

I think I have to use the fact that if $f : G\to H$ is a continuous homomorphism between Lie groups then $f$ is smooth. In particular, I should apply this to $\operatorname{Id}_G : G\to G$ but I am not sure how this gives us the result.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2858695/354840) might be of interest.

Comment: The trick is to spell out the exact meaning of your question: You have to show that if $G_1, G_2$ are two (smooth) Lie groups and $\phi: G_1\to G_2$ is a homeomorphic isomorphism, then $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism. Is $\phi$ is smooth? What about $\phi^{-1}$?