# Continuous homomorphisms between Lie groups are smooth

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the proof of the fact that continuous homomorphisms between Lie groups are smooth from these lecture notes:  https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/weiyi_zhang/ma4e0.pdf

The result is Theorem 2.6.11 in the notes and is on page 30.

After showing that $p$ is smooth, bijective and a group homomorphism, how does it follows that $dp$ has constant rank and hence must be bijective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p:G\to H$ is any smooth homomorphism between Lie groups, then $dp$ has constant rank.  Indeed, for each $g\in G$, $$p\circ L_g=L_{p(g)}\circ p$$ since $p$ is a homomorphism (where $L_g$ denotes left translation by $g$).  Taking the differential at $e$ on both sides, we get $$dp_g\circ d(L_g)_e=d(L_{p(g)})_e\circ dp_e.$$ Since $L_g$ and $L_{p(g)}$ are diffeomorphisms, this means $dp_g$ and $dp_e$ have the same rank.